# U-Boot: NOR+NAND: UBI Error:

Tags: u-boot, ubifs

In a particular scenario I'm using NOR + NAND configuration with U-Boot on NOR and ubi image(kernel+fs) on NAND.

For the first time, U-boot(2016) can read the UBI image and loads the kernel successfully without any error as follows.

```
ubi0: attaching mtd2
ubi0: attached mtd2 (name "mtd=0", size 32 MiB)
ubi0: PEB size: 131072 bytes (128 KiB), LEB size: 126976 bytes
ubi0: min./max. I/O unit sizes: 2048/2048, sub-page size 2048
ubi0: VID header offset: 2048 (aligned 2048), data offset: 4096
ubi0: good PEBs: 256, bad PEBs: 0, corrupted PEBs: 0
ubi0: user volume: 3, internal volumes: 1, max. volumes count: 128
ubi0: max/mean erase counter: 1/0, WL threshold: 4096, image sequence number: 191496598
ubi0: available PEBs: 134, total reserved PEBs: 122, PEBs reserved for bad PEB handling: 20
Read 0 bytes from volume kernel to 84000000
No size specified -> Using max size (2793472)
## Loading kernel from FIT Image at 84000000 ...
```

But when try rebooting, the very next time I endup with UBI error as follows.

```
ubi0: attaching mtd2
ubi0: scanning is finished
UBI error: cannot attach mtd2
UBI init error 22
```

It seems like when UBI is read for the first time, U-Boot does some stamping or changes in the UBI header or something but I couldn't clearly find what causes this problem and which part of the u-boot code should I look into.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the UBI configuration is the same for Kernel and uboot. Run ubinfo in both environment and check each info one-by-one.

A possible error is the PEB number, Kernel will reserve 2% (20/1024) blocks, but uboot only reserves 1% (CONFIG_MTD_UBI_BEB_RESERVE 1)

Also make sure you have the same NAND-ECC scheme for both Kernel e U-Boot.